# how can i use KafkaLoggingHandler to connect multiple brokers?

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

I've written KafkaLoggingHandler as shown below , how can i use KafkaLoggingHandler to connect multiple brokers?

```
kafka_log_handler = KafkaLoggingHandler(
     local_kafka-1_1:9092, # ex:how can i add local_kafka-2_1??
     ...
     ...
)
```

This is my docker-compose.yml , i create two clusters by kafka images.

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka-1:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9095:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka1.test.local
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9095
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /kafka/logs
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 500
      KAFKA_offsets_topic_replication_factor: 3
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ${KAFKA_DATA}/500:/kafka

  kafka-2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9096:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka2.test.local
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9096
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /kafka/logs
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 501
      KAFKA_offsets_topic_replication_factor: 3
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ${KAFKA_DATA}/501:/kafka
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just comma-separate them

`'kafka1.test.local:9095,kafka2.test.local:9096'`

However, the bootstrap protocol would handle this for you, so the only reason to specify multiple brokers is for client fault-tolerance (and running multiple brokers on the same machine does not guarantee any fault tolerance)

Comment: it worked! thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry, i found an issue in my project, I use the 'kafka1.test.local:9095,kafka2.test.local:9096' to create two brokers, but when I kill the kafka1.test.local:9095 or kafka2.test.local:9096', the other active brokers can not be worked(name or service not know,Is your advertised.listeners(called advertised.host.name before kafka 9)), do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: As the error says, make sure the advertised names are correct

Comment: good! is very useful! thanks for your help!